# AIR Linux - ADT Failed to load the AIR Runtime

Tags: linux, apache-flex, air, adt, argument-dependent-lookup

i've just added air-sdk to ubuntu, and adl is working, but when im trying to use adt i have this:

Failed to load the AIR Runtime

What i can do whit this?

I need adt to make native installer from .air file to .dbm

"adt -package -target native my-app-name.dbm my-app-name.air "

Before i changed the air-sdk it was always working like a harm!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: - delete flex-sdk and just leave air-sdk - 
need to use adl and adt from air-sdk - not from flex-sdk